# Convert Word 2007 Document to Word 2003 Programmatically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

Does anyone know of any component or library (preferably open source) that would allow me to convert Word 2007 documents to Word 2003 with ASP.NET?

Comment: Do you mean converting using .NET, rather than ASP.NET?

Comment: Hah, yes that's what I meant Richard. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a followup, I was given the go-ahead to use Aspose.Words for .NET.  I appreciate your comments and suggestions to this question. Thank you!

Comment: You can go ahead and mark your answer as the best answer with the hollow check mark next to this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you instead install (or have your users install) the [Microsoft Office Compatability Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=941B3470-3AE9-4AEE-8F43-C6BB74CD1466&displaylang=en)? This allows Word 2003 to open documents saved by Word 2007 in both binary (.doc) and XML (.docx) formats.

If you have a stream of 2007 documents arriving at your company then maybe you could write a Word 2003 Add-In that uses a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor a folder in which the files get placed. It would then open and re-save the files to a new location, in 2003 format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard. I actually thought about that once before, but the company I work for is huge, and getting something like that deployed across the enterprise is painful. :)

Comment: @Kevin: Fair enough. I updated my response with an additional suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To use Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) you need to install Office 2007 on server.

[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
public virtual void SaveAs (
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object FileName,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object FileFormat,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object LockComments,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object Password,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object AddToRecentFiles,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object WritePassword,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object ReadOnlyRecommended,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object EmbedTrueTypeFonts,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object SaveNativePictureFormat,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object SaveFormsData,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object SaveAsAOCELetter,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object Encoding,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object InsertLineBreaks,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object AllowSubstitutions,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object LineEnding,
    [OptionalAttribute] ref Object AddBiDiMarks
)
```

You need to specify custom `FileFormat` from [WdSaveFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat.aspx) enumeration.

I didn't found how to force exatly old, 2003 format but you can save it in RTF (`WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF`)